# add whitespace <span> on space bar

Tags: jquery

I currently have this function:

```
if (e.keyCode == 32){
    var $cursor = $("#cursor")
    $cursor.val("");
    this.append("<span class = 'space'>-</span>");
    $cursor.insertAfter(".space:last");
    $cursor.focus();
}
```

I was wondering how one would add a whitespace for the span, right now I add a dash for testing.

Comment: `&nbsp;` should work, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried just using a space character?

```
//...
this.append("<span class = 'space'> </span>");
//...
```

If that doesn't work, you can use `&nbsp;` (nonbreaking space) instead of `-`.

```
//...
this.append("<span class = 'space'>&nbsp;</span>");
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way could be to use CSS:

```
Test<span class="spacer"></span>Test

.spacer {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Byy2e/